# FTOA: Let $f(z) = |a_nz^n + .. + a_1z + a_0|$. Show $f(z)$ has a minimizer $z^*$ and complex sum converges for $|z| \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, proof-verification

I've been looking into this proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra:

http://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/another-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra/

In the proof we have $f(z) = |p(z)| = |a_nz^n + ... + a_1z + a_0|$ and we show $f(z) \rightarrow \infty$ when $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ by claiming $$|a_n + \frac {a_{n-1}} z + ... + \frac {a_1} {z^{n-1}} + \frac {a_0} {z^{n}}|$$ converges to $a_n$ when $|z| \rightarrow \infty$

This in turn implies $f(z)$ has a minimizer $z^* \in \mathbb C$.

Can someone show formally why the sum in modulus converges to $a_n$? And why this implies $f(z)$ has a minimizer $z^* \in \mathbb C$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, we have

$$\left| \left(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right) - a_n \right| \leq \left| \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} \right| + \ldots+ \left| \frac{a_0}{z^n} \right|. \tag{1}$$

Let $a := \max\{|a_0|,\ldots,|a_{n-1}|\}$, then $(1)$ shows

$$\left| \left(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right) - a_n \right| \leq  \frac{n \cdot a}{|z|}$$

for any $|z| \geq 1$. Letting $|z| \to \infty$ we find

$$\left| \left(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right) - a_n \right| \to 0$$

i.e.

$$\left(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right) \to a_n. \tag{2}$$

This proves the first claim. By definition,

$$f(z) = \left|z^n \cdot \left(a_n + \frac{a_{n-1}}{z} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{z^n}\right) \right|$$

and therefore $(2)$ implies $f(z) \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$. In particular, we can choose an arbitrary $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and find $R \geq 0$ such that $f(z) \geq f(z_0)$ for any $|z| \geq R$. Since $f$ is continous, hence attains its minimum on compact sets, there exists $z^\ast \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z^\ast| \leq R$, such that $$f(z^{\ast}) = \min_{z \in \mathbb{C}} f(z)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer. However just because $f(z) \rightarrow \infty$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ why does this imply we can pick $z_0$ and find $R \ge 0$. ? What if $f$ starts going towards infinity from $R \ge a\in \mathbb R$ and before that increase and decrease with no obvious pattern ? How does one proove $f(z)$ attains its minimum on some set in $\mathbb C$ - What if $f(z) \rightarrow - \infty$ somewhere near the origin ?

Comment: @user111854 Note that $f$ is continuous, hence bounded on any compact set. Therefore, it is in particular bounded on (closed) balls centered at the origin.

Comment: Thank you. You justify $f$ being continuous because $p$ is a complex polynomial and complex polynomials are continuous ?
$f$ being continuous implies $f$ is defined for every $z\in  \mathbb C$ and right and left limits exists (ie. $< \infty$) and are equal? So this means we have for any $R > 0$ a set $S = \{z | \mid z \in  \mathbb C \land |z| < R\}$ of points. Let $Z = f(S)$ be the image of $S$ on $f$. How does one prove for this set of real numbers there is a minimum ? Can you point me to this theorem ?

Comment: @user111854 Yes, $f$ is continuous as a composition of the continuous functions. That $f$ attains its mimimum on compact sets follows from the [extrem value theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Extreme_Value_Theorem). Note that the closed ball $B[0,R] := \{z \in \mathbb{C}; |z| \leq R\}$ is compact; thus, $f$ attains its mimimum on $B[0,R]$.